# Puppeteer custom error messages when failure

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, mocha.js, puppeteer

I am trying to create a custom error messages when Puppeteer fails to do a task, in my case it cannot find the field that it has to click.

```
    let page;

    before(async () => { /* before hook for mocha testing */
        page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto("https://www.linkedin.com/login");
        await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 1040 });
    });

    after(async function () { /* after hook for mocah testing */
        await page.close();
    });

    it('should login to home page', async () => { /* simple test case */
        const emailInput = "#username";
        const passwordInput = "#assword";
        const submitSelector = ".login__form_action_container ";

        linkEmail = await page.$(emailInput);

        linkPassword = await page.$(passwordInput)
        linkSubmit = await page.$(submitSelector);

        await linkEmail.click({ clickCount: 3 });
        await linkEmail.type('testemail@example.com'); // add the email address for linkedin //

        await linkPassword.click({ clickCount: 3 }).catch(error => {
            console.log('The following error occurred: ' + error);
        });;

        await linkPassword.type('testpassword'); // add password for linkedin account

        await linkSubmit.click();
        await page.waitFor(3000);
    });
});
```

I have deliberately put a wrong passwordInput name in order to force puppeteer to fail. However, the console.log message is never printed. 
This is my error output which is the default mocha error:

```
  simple test for Linkedin Login functionality
    1) should login to home page


  0 passing (4s)
  1 failing

  1) simple test for Linkedin Login functionality
       should login to home page:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/sample.spec.js:29:28)
```

Line 29 is the `await linkPassword.click({ clickCount: 3 })`

Anyone has an idea how I can make it print a custom error message when an error like this occurs?

Comment: Adding a try/catch won't work?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the exception is being thrown not in the result of the function `await linkPassword.click()` execution, but in the result of attempt of executing the function. By `.catch()` you try to handle an eventual exception thrown during execution. `page.$()` works this way it returns a null if a selector isn't found. And in your case, you execute `null.click({ clickCount: 3 }).catch()` what actually doesn't have sense.

To quickly solve your problem you should do a check to verify whether `linkPassword` isn't null. However, I think you make a big mistake by using `page.$()` to get an element to interact with. This way you lose a lot of the puppeteer features because instead to use puppeteer's method `page.click()` you use a simple browser's `click()` in the browser.

Instead, you should make sure that the element exists and is visible and then use the puppeteer's API to play with the element. Like this:

```
    const emailInput = "#username";

    await page.waitForSelector(emailInput);
    await page.click(emailInput, { clickCount: 3 });
    await page.type(emailInput, 'testemail@example.com')
```

Thanks to that your script makes sure the element is clickable and if it is it scrolls to the element and performs clicks and types the text.

Then you can handle a case when the element isn't found this way:

```
   page.waitForSelector(emailInput).catch(() => {})
```

or just by using `try/catch`.